# 'Child of' constraint not working on armature

Tags: animation, constraints

Basically i am trying to make some first person shooter animations and i just can't get the child of constraint to work, [image: i]

[image]
As you can see, i tried setting the constraint on the right hand so that it would move/stick with the gun but it did not work. I'm still new to blender and would appreciate a solution

Comment: Please share your file. I want to test a theory. https://blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 0):

The hand bone you're trying to constraint is a connected child of another bone, so it isn't free to move.

Try to do the opposite, and make the main gun bone a constrained child of an appropriate hand bone.

After settign up the constraint, press its "Set inverse" button.